# Blank page while running selenium scripts on Iphone

Tags: java, iphone, ios, selenium-webdriver

I have successfully build the iWebDriver on iphone 4s ( provisioning profiles are also installed ).

I am able to ping ip address of Phone ( which is displayed when WebDriver is started on phone at the bottom "`http://XXX.XX.XX.XX/wd/hub`" ) from my mac and also mac ip adress from iphone ( using ip scanning app ).

Now while running scripts from my mac, I am still seeing blank white screen in the phone ( when driver.get(URL) is executed ) with commands at the bottom of the blank screen ( setURL: ).

I tried to open URL via iPhone Safari manually and it works fine.

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:3001/wd/hub"), 
DesiredCapabilities.iphone());
driver.get(URL);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Try

```
driver.navigate().to("www.bbc.co.uk");
```

**Instead of**

```
driver.get();
```

Seemed to fix my issue.